# Remove Conflict between JQuery and Prototype.js in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, prototype-js

I have included all the js library in page.xml of my magento.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
```

after that also my prototype.js is not working. I have used noconflict.js also. It was working properly before. After merging the js files it is giving the errors.

Comment: only `noconflict.js` this will not work you have to replace variable `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: What should I have to do then? As I am very new to magento and javascript

Comment: add this `var jQuery=$.noConflict();`  in start of file every jquery related file. and replace every `$` with `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only `noconflict.js` this will not work you have to replace variable `$` with `jQuery`
add this `var jQuery=$.noConflict();` in start of file every jquery related file. and replace every `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: There are a lot of js files how it is possible to change all $ with jQuery.

Comment: you have to otherwise conflict still there.

Comment: I have replaced all $ with jQuery but it still conflicting

Comment: Previously some how it was working now totally stopped working.

Comment: i think you added some new files you need to replace it there.

Answer (score 1):

go ahead and add the contents of noconflict.js directly at the end of your jquery file , this will ensure that it gets executed right after jquery is loaded

Comment: I have added the noconflict.js also but it is conflicting

Comment: @Anton S, please provide me more detail. I also faced the problem. When I merge and minify JS file, a lot of jQuery Conflict are occurred. Do I need to add noconflict.js at end of the local.xml file?

Comment: you need to understand what is causing the conflict,  adding something to somewhere is meaningless hack that won't get you far