# Add to Cart Button Not Working

Tags: prototype-js

I'm having an issue with the Add to Cart Button on my website. The error I am receiving is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
```

The link to the preview of this site is:

http://southeastsupfix.safetechhosting.co.uk/index.php/cp5000-429.html

Here is the fully list of errors that I get:

[image: Errors]

I am sensing a possible JQuery conflict but I can't quite see where.

In terms of the inclusion of files, I had added these in the `head.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/prototype.js"></script>
```

I have also tried the latest version of JQuery but I get the same issues.

If anyone has experienced this before I'd be great if I could get some information.

Comment: it's a jquery conflict with prototype. follow this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113255/remove-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype-js-in-magento-1-9-1/113259#113259

Answer (score 0):

This is simple **jQuery** and **prototype** conflict problem.

You will need to resolve conflict of **prototype** and **jQuery** to fix this issue.

To solve this, you need to include jQuery main file before prototype.js and also include **jQuery.noconflict.js** file just after jQuery main file.

Content of **jQuery.noconflict.js** should be:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your answer, I have now done the following: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/jQuery.noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/prototype.js"></script>` and inside the jQuery.noconflict.js file I have included `jQuery.noConflict();` but  I am still encountering the same issue.

Comment: There is another prototype.js being included in page.
You need to include your files in Magento's way

Comment: Oh I see, out of curiosity, what is the Magento way of including files such as prototype.js?